# How do you correctly access the defined models from a sequelize instance?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've seen this syntax to access a defined model from the Sequelize instance:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username'[, 'password']);

var Project = sequelize.define('Project', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
});

sequelize.Project.build({});
```

However, when I tried it myself on 1.7.0:

```
console.log(sequelize.Project);
```

Returned `undefined`

Is there another way or a correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the object on your own. Usually people do something like:

```
sequelize.Project = sequelize.import('./models/project');
```

Sequelize doesn't do that for you. (The fact that people decide to attach models to the sequelize object is purely a convenience thing that emerged)

Source: [Github Issues #1693](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1693)

Answer (score 2):

I use this way:
`sequelize.models.Project`

Answer (score -1):

you need to save it afterwards and catch the events in callbacks. something like:

```
Project.save().success(function(err, project) {
     console.log(project)

    })
```

or:

```
Project
      .create({})
      .complete(function(err,project){

      console.log(project)
})
```